# How did Dr. Zoidberg know his parents growing up when they supposedly died upon his conception?

Tags: futurama

There are multiple flashbacks and lines in Futurama that imply Dr. Zoidberg knew and was raised by his "parents"... But, Zoidberg's species dies when they successfully mate, right? So how could he ever know his biological parents?

Perhaps Zoidberg was adopted? Or maybe decapodians are haplo-diploid and he's a genetic male clone of his mother? Anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 6):

It's true that they died upon Zoidberg's conception. However, some older generation has to be there to care for the babies and teach them about the world. So it's possible that the parents Zoidberg refers to are simply Decapods that took it upon themselves to raise him.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Answer (score 0):

Zoidberg's "parents" are never really mentioned. He does mention other family members, with there even being a full episode where he goes to Hollywood to see his uncle. But apart from various episodes to do with other family members, there is no evidence to suggest that he knew his parents. It may just have been another family member who raised him. After all, how could he know any of his extended family if he was supposedly adopted?

Comment: in one of the episodes their is a small flash back to Zoidberg's childhood and he is told "You can be a comedian... If you want your parents to roll over in their graves." later in the same episode. "Sure you can go to medical school... if you have given up on your dream of being a comedian."

Comment: @alex Both of which can be read to imply that his parents are dead.  I just rewatched that episode, and there's no statement of who the adult female Decapodian is.  They don't refer to her as Zoidberg's mother/aunt/foster-parent.